# Angular Select in FormControl / Formbuilder dosen't select option

Tags: angular, select, formbuilder

i'm making a form for edit some items and a Select with options where select different categories, i load from a DB, but when i build the component with form formBuilder/control set up correct name and description from db but it dosen't select the right "category", no one category get selected

what i'm making wrong?

my ItemFormComponent

```
export class ItemFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() item?: ItemModule;

  categories?: ItemCategoryModule[];
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private itemService: ItemsService, private itemsCategoryService: ItemsCategoryService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [''],
      description: [''],
      category: [''],
    });

    this.getCategories();

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    if (this.route.snapshot.params['id'] > 0) {
      this.itemService.getById(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe((x: any) => {
          this.item = x;
        });
    }
    if (this.item) {
      this.form.patchValue(this.item);
    }
  }

  get f() { return this.form.controls; }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }

  onChange(deviceValue:any) {
    console.log(this.form);
  }

  private getCategories() {
    this.itemsCategoryService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.categories = data.results;
    });
  }

}
```

my template

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control">

  <input type="text" formControlName="description" class="form-control">

  <label for="category">Order</label>
  <select formControlName="category" id="category" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let category of categories;" 
    [ngValue]="category">
      {{category.name}} 
    </option>
  </select>

  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

i tried  `[attr.selected]=" category.id == f['category'].value.id  ? true : null"`  inside option but inside DOM appear  `selected="True"`  on right item but actualy dosen't select it did you know why? there is a way a compare function to rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

seem i solved the problem with

```
  <select [compareWith]="compareCategory" formControlName="category" id="category" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

and inside ts file

```
  compareCategory(cat1: ItemCategoryModule, cat2: ItemCategoryModule) {
    return cat1 && user2 ? cat1.id === cat2.id : cat1 === cat2;
  }
```